# shortest path from single source to single destination in a non-negative weighted grid (n,5)

Tags: algorithm, graph, grid, time-complexity

I have a grid with n columns and 5 rows.

Each edge is weighted and non-negative. i need to start from the bottom-left corner and get to the top-right corner with the shortest path.

I found it in O(N^2) complexity but i need it in linear time O(n).

I would be grateful for some help.

How I solved a grid (n,2) in linear time:

the bottom left is 0, and then i start looking for it's neighbors with a few comparisons. after i found the minimum from the beginning to them, i go to their neighbors and do the same, this I do until i get to the end.

I delt with each vertex and each edge once and therefore it is linear.

Thank you in advance,

Yaron.

Comment: You may use Dijkstra's Shortest path algorithm. But it runs in O(NlogN) time using heap data structure.

Comment: Is it possible that resulting path (c1,c2,...,cm) contains all grid cells? Or this is uniform-cost search?

Answer (score 0):

In this Graph you have `5n` vertices and `5*4*n` edges so `V=5n` and `E=20n`.
You can easily apply Dijkstra using priority_queue for retrieval of min vertex which will result in time complexity of O(VlogV + ElogE) which is in this case O(N*logN).

[Dijkstra wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).It contains the sudo code.

You can also find it's C++ implementation if you search in google but make sure it uses priority_queue otherwise it will take log(N^2) time. If you don't find it send me a comment and I will send you it's implementation.

Comment: thanks. the thing is that the dijkstra algorithm works for any non-negative weighted graph, and here i have a grid (planar graph) and I want to use the grid's properties to lower the complexity.

Comment: I am using your grid property by taking maximum number of edges of a vertex to be 4, which result in this time complexity and I think that your needs will be fulfilled by O(NlogN) because it is just a little bit higher than O(N).

Comment: but dijkstra is O(NlogN) anyways, even if the graph is not a grid. i am looking for something unique for a (n,5) grid.

Comment: @user76508 A graph is a graph irrespective of how you represent it.

Comment: if you have a grid (n,2) then it is possible to solve in linear time. i am trying to do the same with (n,5).

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to correct me, but you cant do it in linear time, its more or less impossible*

Having a grid format doesnt make it easier to work with.

*without using paticular constraints

Comment: i was successful solving grid (n,2) in linear time and that's why i believe it is possible for grid (n,5) in linear time to.

Comment: Because in the (n,2) you probably didn't really do it in linear time, you did it in O(M*N) where N=2.

If you post your alg we can discuss it more

Comment: i posted my algorithm for grid (n,2).

Comment: Hate to break it to you, if your working with an undirected weighted graph you didn't do it linearly.  Assuming that you processed every edge and vertex exactly once (which you shouldnt be doing and i dont think you did) you did it in O(E*V) when E < 3.  The agorithms posted above are better than O(E*V).


Also you didnt process Each Edge and vertex exactly once, as you should be processing the middle Edges twice, once for each neighbour.

Comment: there are no middle edges - there is a top edge and a bottom edge.

Comment: Thats not a grid, This is a [grid](http://harablog.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/symmetry.png). Yours is a a graph with 2 nodes and 2 edges, your (n,5) is just a graph with 2 nodes and 5 edges.  Its trivial to find out how to do this.

Plus in the (n,5) case, youre still processing the bottom and horizontal edges multiple times.